# gzip read file succeed first time but fails the second time I call it

Tags: c++, boost, io, gzip

I was using boost gzip to read zipped file. my program runs fine when I call it the first time. But when I call the same function the second time. It fails. I don't know why it only worked once. Thanks!

```
void readcheckfile(const char* _checkname,queue<Graphnode> &_q)
{

    int _dep;
    int _val;
    Graphnode currentNode;
    cout<<"hererererererer\n";
    fstream _checkfile(_checkname, fstream::in | fstream::binary);
    cout<<"tthererererererer\n";
    std::stringstream _data;
    boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> in;
    in.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
    in.push(_checkfile);
    boost::iostreams::copy(in, _data);

    cout<<"aaaatthererererererer\n";
    //fstream _checkfile;
    //_checkfile.open(_checkname,fstream::in);
    _data>>_dep;
    while(_data.good())
    {
        currentNode.depth=(unsigned char)_dep;
        _data>>_val;
        currentNode.x=(unsigned char)_val;
        for(i=0;i<16;i++)
        {
            _data>>_val;
            currentNode.state[i]=(unsigned char)_val;
        }
        _q.push(currentNode);
    }
    _checkfile.close();
    //exit(0);
}
```

when I call it twice
the terminal returns:

```
hererererererer
tthererererererer
aaaatthererererererer

hererererererer
tthererererererer
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

=====================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   EXIT CODE: 6
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
=====================================================================================
```

Comment: The gzip decompressor doesn't read zip archives, but gzip compressed files.

Comment: As for your problem, you should run your program in a debugger. Then it will stop at the point of the failure and you can examine the function call stack so you can find out where in your program the crash happened.

Comment: Since you're not necessarily flushing `cout`, you can't really tell how far the program got. Use `endl` instead of "\n" or flush explicitly. And a debugger.

Comment: You also fall in a common trap, that you use e.g. `while (stream.good())`. The flags for failure or eof will not be set until _after_ you attempt an I/O operation. So in your case you will loop once and then `_data>>_val` will fail but you still do processing using the failed data.

Comment: No, it will not fail. it only fails when I attempt to read another file. It works fine for reading one single file. my file is like 20
8 12 11 9 13 3 15 10 14 0 5 1 6 2 7 4 8
10 12 11 9 13 3 15 10 14 2 1 0 6 7 5 4 8
8 12 11 9 13 3 15 10 14 0 2 1 6 7 5 4 8
5 12 11 9 13 3 0 10 14 2 15 1 6 7 5 4 8
15 12 11 9 13 3 15 10 14 2 5 6 8 7 4 1 0
7 12 11 9 13 3 15 10 0 2 5 6 14 7 4 1 8
...